# React-native and Redux with combineReducers - Access other state/property?

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm starting with React-Native and Redux. I'm using combineReducers to make my reducer live easy, passing just the element that I need (from 'global' state).

This is my idea of state and my code for combineReducers:

State:

```
{
   race: [ {...}, {...}, {...}],
   pilots: [ {...}, {...}, {...}],
   <other stuff>
}
```

Code:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    race: addLapReducer,
    pilots: editingPilotsReducer
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer, devToolsEnhancer());
```

This is working fine as expected. The only problem is that I need to access 'pilots' array from 'addLapReducer'. Is this possible? If yes, how?
I know that if I create my store with only one reducer (instead of combineReducer), the full state will be sent to my reducer......but is not the case here.
One thing that I tought if using both: combinedReducers and 'standard' reducer, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Li357, I need to split my reducers to sepate my code. The only thing why I need to access another part of store is because I need to fetch name of pilot....it's kind of foreign key, but it's 'optional'. Do be clear: in the race, every item is a transponder and I want to get pilot name (of this transponder) which is 'saved' in 'pilots' key of store. I have only two reducers that need to access 2 diferent keys. All other recuders only need to access their own key (that's why I'm using separeted recuders do reduce code).

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem is that I need to access 'pilots' array from 'addLapReducer'

I believe a better place to access the `pilots` array is from the action creator in which you return an action with a type handled by `addLapReducer`.

Say for example you have an action creator that looks like this:

```
function somethingLaps() {
  return {type: ADD_LAPS, payload: 1}
}
```

You can change that to return a function with the `dispatch` argument as well as `getState`, in order to access the `pilots` array:

```
function somethingLaps() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({type: ADD_LAPS, payload: 1})
    let {pilots} = getState()
    // I'm making up what you might have needed pilots array for
    // add a new pilot
    let newPilots = pilots.concat([{
      name: 'Chesley Sullenberger',
      nickname: 'Sully'
    }])
    dispatch({type: UPDATE_PILOTS, payload: newPilots})
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, work with actionCreators! But doesn't solve my problem, because I need to retrieve pilot name, not insert a new one :( .
Also, I'm thinking about something else. I have total counters in global store that I would like to update when new laps arrive (total race time, total laps, fast lap, etc...). This is not related to 'race' key, but 'counters' key. Another key that I need to access :(
Would be cool if I can access global state with one reducer and key's only on another reducers (using combineReducers). This would solve my problem.

Comment: Retrieve which pilot's name? If you know based on the index of the pilots array, you can pass that index to the `somethingLaps` function or whatever you name it. Otherwise, if you have a unique field like the pilot's name/id, you can get the index of which element in the array needs to be updated by doing something like `let index = pilots.map(pilot => pilot.id).indexOf(index)`

Comment: in race state, i have tx_id.....the same field in 'pilots' state. Then, when new lap arrives, I need to fill 'pilot' field (of state 'race') with pilot name. Can I access both states during render and retrieve pilot name there? Yes! But I need to have both states in this component, causing too much refresh on data update (in pilots, for example)....right? Also, this doesn't solve my problem of counters (total time from all laps/racers, total laps, best lap, etc..), which reside on 'counters' state. Any sugestion? :(

Comment: The "Tips' on reac-redux are to use combineRecuders at hierarchy level or make my own combineReducers. Both I think should work for me, but I don't have any idea how to implement any :( 
Maybe custom function works better....I could pass some param to say if this reducers should receiver global state of key-specific.....but I don't know how to do this.